# Centering text in longtable

Tags: longtable

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
   Total number of random points $n=20$.\\
Set $\text{Count}=0,M=\sqrt{\dfrac 32} , a= \dfrac 12 , b=  \dfrac 32$  
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{| p{.02\textwidth} | p{.05\textwidth} |p{.05\textwidth} |p{.15\textwidth} |p{0.38\textwidth} |} 
        \hline 
        $i$ &$x_i$  &$y_i$  &$f(x_i)= \sqrt x_i$    &$\text{Count}$\\
            &       &       &               &(If $y_i \le\sqrt x_i$, set $\text{Count}= \text{Count}+1$)\\\hline\endhead
        1   &1.497  &0.524  &1.224  &1\\\hline
        2   &1.319  &0.479  &1.148  &2\\\hline
        3   &1.211  &0.420  &1.100  &3\\\hline
        4   &0.522  &1.139  &0.722  &   \\\hline
        5   &0.924  &0.480  &0.961  &4\\\hline
        6   &1.069  &1.211  &1.034  &   \\\hline
        7   &0.883  &0.757  &0.940  &5\\\hline
        8   &1.127  &0.082  &1.062  &6\\\hline
        9   &0.796  &0.654  &0.892  &7\\\hline
        10  &1.082  &0.272  &1.040  &8\\\hline
        11  &1.443  &0.468  &1.201  &9\\\hline
        12  &1.084  &1.162  &1.041  &   \\\hline
        13  &1.427  &0.143  &1.195  &10\\\hline
        14  &0.509  &0.612  &0.713  &11\\\hline
        15  &0.579  &0.372  &0.761  &12\\\hline
        16  &1.422  &0.534  &1.192  &13\\\hline
        17  &1.129  &0.707  &1.063  &14\\\hline
        18  &0.789  &0.546  &0.888  &15\\\hline
        19  &1.442  &1.068  &1.201  &16\\\hline
        20  &1.393  &0.352  &1.180  &17\\\hline 
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How to centre data in 4th nd 5th column?

[image: Image added]

Comment: Off-topic: ***Never*** encase a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment.

Comment: Also off-topic: Why are you using `\dfrac` while in inline math mode?

Comment: @Mico no such thing.. just wanted to make the fraction bigger

Comment: You should probably replace all instances of `\sqrt x_i` with `\sqrt{x_i}`...

Comment: @Mico didn't bother me.. I think it's same as `\frac 12` and `\frac{1}{2}` except anything attached to it

Comment: add `array` package then use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{...}` but your example gives `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \text`

Comment: @ManjoyDas - `\sqrt x_i` ends up placing the surd just above `x`, not `x_i`. Are you taking the i'th square root of `x`, or the square root of `x_i`?

Comment: @Mico thanks for the information!! It was sqrt of `x_i`

Comment: your columns are too narrow for your text `Overfull \hbox (3.94821pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 30--30
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 19|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you employ the basic `c` column type for the first four columns; since the ability to perform automatic line-breaking is not a requirement for these columns, why use the `p` column type? And, do use a centered version of the `p` column type for the final column.

It's also much better to write

```
$\text{Count}=0$, $M=\sqrt{\dfrac 32}$, $a= \dfrac 12$, $b=  \dfrac 32$.
```

instead of

```
$\text{Count}=0,M=\sqrt{\dfrac 32} , a= \dfrac 12 , b=  \dfrac 32$
```

since you're talking about four little formulas, not one long and complicated formula.

Finally, I would recommend you employ inline-fraction notation, *not* `\dfrac`, while in inline math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,longtable}
\newlength\mylen
% determine width of final column:
\settowidth\mylen{$\mathrm{Count}= \mathrm{Count}+1$} 

\begin{document}
Total number of random points $n=20$.

Set $\mathrm{Count}=0$, $M=\sqrt{3/2}$, $a= 1/2$, and $b= 3/2$. 

\begin{longtable}{| c | c | c | c | 
         >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mylen} |} 
    \hline 
    $i$ & $x_i$ & $y_i$ & $f(x_i)=\sqrt{x_i}$ & 
    $\mathrm{Count}$: \\
    & & & & If $y_i \le\sqrt{x_i}$, set $\mathrm{Count}= \mathrm{Count}+1$ \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    
    1  & 1.497 & 0.524 & 1.224 & 1\\ \hline
    2  & 1.319 & 0.479 & 1.148 & 2\\ \hline
    3  & 1.211 & 0.420 & 1.100 & 3\\ \hline
    4  & 0.522 & 1.139 & 0.722 &  \\ \hline
    5  & 0.924 & 0.480 & 0.961 & 4\\ \hline
    6  & 1.069 & 1.211 & 1.034 &  \\ \hline
    7  & 0.883 & 0.757 & 0.940 & 5\\ \hline
    8  & 1.127 & 0.082 & 1.062 & 6\\ \hline
    9  & 0.796 & 0.654 & 0.892 & 7\\ \hline
    10 & 1.082 & 0.272 & 1.040 & 8\\ \hline
    11 & 1.443 & 0.468 & 1.201 & 9\\ \hline
    12 & 1.084 & 1.162 & 1.041 &  \\ \hline
    13 & 1.427 & 0.143 & 1.195 & 10\\ \hline
    14 & 0.509 & 0.612 & 0.713 & 11\\ \hline
    15 & 0.579 & 0.372 & 0.761 & 12\\ \hline
    16 & 1.422 & 0.534 & 1.192 & 13\\ \hline
    17 & 1.129 & 0.707 & 1.063 & 14\\ \hline
    18 & 0.789 & 0.546 & 0.888 & 15\\ \hline
    19 & 1.442 & 1.068 & 1.201 & 16\\ \hline
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17\\ \hline 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I need `if y_i\le \sqrt{x_i}` part just below `count`

Comment: @ManjoyDas - Please see the updated answer.

Comment: You could make the last column a c column and just put the title into a `\parbox[t]`.

Answer (score 2):

- With `tabularray` package ...
- Do you really need long table?
- Does it can have at bottom of table (except on the last page= notes that table is continued on the next page?
- An example with no caption and no text at bottom of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}{}                       % <---
\begin{longtblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {c cc cc},
                 row{1} = {mode=math},
                 rowhead = 1,
                 }
i   & x_i   & y_i   & f(x_i)=\sqrt{x_i} &   \begin{array}{l}
                                            \text{Count}:\\
                                            \text{If }y_i \le\sqrt{x_i}:\\
                                            \text{set } \mathrm{Count}=\mathrm{Count}+1
                                            \end{array}\\
    1  & 1.497 & 0.524 & 1.224 & 1  \\
    2  & 1.319 & 0.479 & 1.148 & 2  \\
    3  & 1.211 & 0.420 & 1.100 & 3  \\
    4  & 0.522 & 1.139 & 0.722 &    \\
    5  & 0.924 & 0.480 & 0.961 & 4  \\
    6  & 1.069 & 1.211 & 1.034 &    \\
    7  & 0.883 & 0.757 & 0.940 & 5  \\
    8  & 1.127 & 0.082 & 1.062 & 6  \\
    9  & 0.796 & 0.654 & 0.892 & 7  \\
    10 & 1.082 & 0.272 & 1.040 & 8  \\
    11 & 1.443 & 0.468 & 1.201 & 9  \\
    12 & 1.084 & 1.162 & 1.041 &    \\
    13 & 1.427 & 0.143 & 1.195 & 10 \\
    14 & 0.509 & 0.612 & 0.713 & 11 \\
    15 & 0.579 & 0.372 & 0.761 & 12 \\
    16 & 1.422 & 0.534 & 1.192 & 13 \\
    17 & 1.129 & 0.707 & 1.063 & 14 \\
    18 & 0.789 & 0.546 & 0.888 & 15 \\
    19 & 1.442 & 1.068 & 1.201 & 16 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\

    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
    20 & 1.393 & 0.352 & 1.180 & 17 \\
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you like to have bottom of tables text *Continued on the next page*. than replace

```
    \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}{}                       % <---
```

with

```
    \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
```

After this change the compilation result is:

[image]